# SQL Server - Convert one row into a key value multiple rows

Tags: sql-server

I have a table having one row like this:

[image]

And what I need is to convert it into a key value multiple rows like this:

[image]

Any clue?

Comment: Relevant reading: [Microsoft unpivot documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable
(
    Column1 INT
    , Column2 INT
    , Column3 INT
    , Column4 INT
)

INSERT INTO #MyTable VALUES
(1, 8, 3, 5)

SELECT *
FROM #MyTable
UNPIVOT
(
    [Columns] FOR [Column] IN (Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4)
) AS UP
```

Comment: I have 2 columns that are nvarchar instead of INT and im getting an error. The type of column "Column3" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Comment: I just did a CAST to all to same type.